# what are conditions for satisfying $\sup_t M^2_t<\infty$ where $M_t$ is locally square integrable martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes

what are conditions for satisfying $\sup_{t\in[0,T]} M^2_t<\infty$ a.s. where $M_t$ is locally square integrable martingale?

I have no idea, besides using Doob's maximal inequalities, but they give bounds for expectation.
may be some conditions should be imposed on $<M>_\infty$?

Comment: Well unless mistaken those conditions must be quite stricts since it is not true even for a simple Brownian motion as $sup_t B_t^2=\infty$ a.s.

Comment: @TheBridge what about $\sup_{t\in[0,T]} M^2_t<\infty$ a.s.?

Comment: If the expectation is finite dimensional thanks to Doob's inequality (you need at least separabiliry for that), then the supremum is finite a.s.

Comment: @zhoraster $M$ is optional. so $E(M^2_t)=E(<M>_t)<\infty$ is enough?

Comment: Well, I guess Doob inequality holds for optional martingales, but I'm not totally sure. You should try to find this in literature.